# webservice client implementaion in axis2-1.6.2 in java

Tags: java, web-services

I have implemented webservice client in axis2-1.6.2 in java and I get response when I call first time and for subsequent second time I get below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:293)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
 at org.apache.axis2.ccws.CustomerCareServiceStub.subscriberRetrieveLite(CustomerCareServiceStub.java:2380)
        at Prepost.SubscriberRetrieveBalance.subscriberRetrieveLite(SubscriberRetrieveBalance.java:111)
        at Prepost.CheckUser.doGet(CheckUser.java:149)
```

here is the API implementation class constructor which sets unique parameter which is same for all requests

```
public SubscriberRetrieveBalance(String url, String strCON_TimeOut, String strSO_TimeOut) {
    try {
        this.url = url;
        stub = new CustomerCareServiceStub(url);
        ServiceClient sClient = stub._getServiceClient();
        Options options = sClient.getOptions();
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, Constants.VALUE_TRUE);
        options.setProperty(AddressingConstants.WS_ADDRESSING_VERSION, AddressingConstants.Submission.WSA_NAMESPACE);
        //options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(2000);
        TransportInDescription transportIn = new TransportInDescription("HTTP");
        options.setTransportIn(transportIn);
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT, Integer.parseInt(strSO_TimeOut));
        options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Integer.parseInt(strCON_TimeOut));
        sClient.setOptions(options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("Can not find the external id")) {
            System.out.println("Exception ::" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and it is called in a servlet and for performance issue I make object of this class for different-2 states(urls) and saved these object to hashmap when first request comes for respective states then make new object and use that object for subsequent requests for that state

```
SubscriberRetrieveBalance objBal = null;
            BalanceBean bal = new BalanceBean();
            if (mapObj.isEmpty() || (mapObj.get(strIP) == null)) {

                objBal = new SubscriberRetrieveBalance(url, strCON_TimeOut, strSO_TimeOut);
                mapObj.put(strIP, objBal);
            } else {

                objBal = mapObj.get(strIP);
            }
            bal = objBal.subscriberRetrieveLite(strMsisdn, userId, token, strCircleId, strCircleName, strSessionId, strDlgId);
```

first time it gives response and then gives nullpointer exception and above error for all requests that belongs to that state

This code is working fine with axis2-1.5

Is there any change in axis2-1.6.2 version that every time it needs new object of API implemented class

Please suggest.